# Forward ControlEvent from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I want to create a list of planet in a separate controller (my `PlanetPickerViewController`). This controller uses a `UITableView` to display a given list of `Planet`. This works fine.

```
public class PlanetPickerViewController: RxViewController {

    // MARK: - PUBLIC -

    public var selection: ControlEvent<Planet>!

    public init(list: Driver<[Planet]>, active: Planet?) {
        self.list = list
        self.active = active
        super.init(nibName: "PlanetPickerViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    // MARK: - PRIVATE -

    private let list: Driver<[Planet]>
    private let active: Planet?

    // MARK: IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: View life cycle

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initializeTableView()
    }

    private func initializeTableView() {
        self.list.drive(self.tableView.rx.items(reusable: PlanetTableViewCell.self)) { row, planet, cell in
            cell.display(planet)
            cell.isSelected = planet == self.active
        }
        .disposed(by: self)

        self.selection = self.tableView.rx.modelSelected(Planet.self)
    }
}
```

Now I want to forward the event of the user tapping a cell. Usually, I'd create a `PlanetPickerViewControllerDelegate` with a dedicated function to manually forward this event:

```
// PlanetPickerViewControllerDelegate
picker(_ picker: PlanetPickerViewController, didSelect planet: Planet)

// PlanetPickerViewController: UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let planet = self.list[indexPath.row]
    self.delegate?.picker(self, didSelect: planet)
}
```

But with RxSwift I want to replace this delegate by a `ControlEvent<Planet>`. This is what I intended with `public var selection: ControlEvent<Planet>!`. The bad thing is I can't subscribe to it before `viewDidLoad` occurs...

What should I change to be able to subscribe to my `selection` as soon as this controller is instantiated ?

```
let modal = PlanetPickerViewController(list: planets, active: nil)
modal.selection.subscribe { do something }
self.present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Observable<Planet>` and subscribe to it in your main view controller:

```
// PlanetPickerViewController

let didSelectPlanet: Observable<Planet>!

private func initializeTableView() {
    // ...

    self.didSelectPlanet = self.tableView.rx.modelSelected(Planet.self).asObservable()
}


// MainViewController
let modal = PlanetPickerViewController(list: planets, active: nil)
modal.self.didSelectPlanet
     .subscribe(onNext: { _ in /* do something */ })
     .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```